# How to detect a motion event when an onClick listener is there?

Tags: android, onclick, android-listview

I have a `ListView` with `onItemClick()` method . Now I want to detect a touch motion in the screen . Implementing `onTouchEvent()` does not work in this case since I have written already a click listener . So help me how to do it. I need both the on click listener and `onTouchEvent()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement the OnTouchListener(View v, MotionEvent event) to check event.getX() and event.getY() when event.ACTION_DOWN and event.ACTION_UP and compare them to know the motion direction.

Note: you must return true to be able to receive the event.ACTION_UP event.