# 'OnClickListener' is not responding

Tags: android, eclipse, android-imageview, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I am trying to add both `OnClickListener` and `OnTouchListener` to my image view. Following is how the image view is created

```
dialogImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.dialogImage);
```

Following is how the listeners are set

```
dialogImage.setOnClickListener(dialogBoxClicked);
dialogImage.setOnTouchListener(imageViewSwiped);
```

Following is the listener method implementation

```
public OnClickListener dialogBoxClicked = new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
                      //To do has been removed because the code is too big
            }

    };

OnTouchListener imageViewSwiped = new OnSwipeTouchListener()
    {
         public void onSwipeRight() 
         {
             currentlyActiveQuestion++;
             currentWord = words.get(currentlyActiveQuestion);
             setUI();
         }

          public void onSwipeLeft() 
          {
              currentlyActiveQuestion--;
              currentWord = words.get(currentlyActiveQuestion);
              setUI();
          }
    };
```

Here the `OnTouchListener` is implemented by a class called `OnSwipeTouchListener` to monitor left and right swipes. This class can be found here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12938787/1379286

But the problem now is, when I set the `OnTouchListener` to the image view, the `OnClickListener` is not responding / do not do what it should do. ImageView is only responding to `OnTouchListener`. If I remove `OnTouchListener` then the `OnClickListener` works. I tested this in a virtual device WVGA5.1 and Galaxy Nexus in eclipse and not in a real phone because I do not have one.

How can I solve this?

**EDIT**

Any code example will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please try to return `false` from `onDown()` method...

Comment: i think your ontouchlistener overlaps your onclicklistener.. a click an be tantamount to a touch IMO

Comment: your touchListener intercept all touch events (typically indicated by the onDown returning true. hence, the click cannot be detected. see @mach answer instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may call View.performClick() when action_up. This results in the click event being called when an actual click happens. Hope it helps.

```
your_txtView.setOnClickListener(new TextView.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});

your_txtView.setOnTouchListener(new TextView.OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN == event.getAction()) {

    } else if (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()) {
        v.performClick();
    }

    return true;
}
});
```

Comment: OK, is there any possiblility where we can not monitor the actual swiping in a virtual device?

Comment: @Knight: Could you elaborate. Why don't you want to monitor actual swiping? You are doing something on swiping right? Or I didn't understand you properly.

Comment: No, I mean I followed your advice. Now can do swiping and click. But the problem is, most of the times it get "clicked" when I swipe. Sometimes it get clicked and swiped. So I thought it might be because I am using a virtual device, the mouse pointer is the one which indicates the "finger"

Comment: Yes, yes that is because of using a virtual device. Run your code on an actual device it will work.

Answer (score 1):

The OnTouchListener hooks the click-event. Handle the click event in it instead. Check out the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339761/how-to-detect-a-motion-event-when-an-onclick-listener-is-there)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, If you can't have both onTouchListener and onClickListener for the same view. If you want your onClickListener to work, set `clickable="true"` in the XML.